# Using fscanf for a txt file and ignoring everything but letters

Tags: c, file, scanf

Hello I'm writing a program that needs to read from a text file and only takes in the letters of the whole file. It could be something as

Hello, my name is whatever. I'm thinking of trying to write a program: "name!"

What I need to do is only read in the letters so my output would be:

hellomynameiswhateverimthinkingoftryingtowriteaprogramname

I have something of this sort:

```
while (fscanf(ifp2, "%c", &file[i]) != EOF) //scans until end of file
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) //loops a possible 10000, file could possibly be that big
        {
            //printf("Got inside while loop [%d]\n", i); //this just lets me see the loop
            if (fscanf(ifp2, "%c ", &file[i]) == 0) //im trying to see how i can ignore some data
            {
                fscanf(ifp2, "%c ", &file[i]); //scans in the character
            }

        }
    }

for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)//prints the array of characters. 
{
    if(file[i] == NULL)//keeps from printing uninitialized parts of array
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        if (counter % 80 == 0) //makes it print 80 characters per line
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("%c", file[i]);//prints the character
        counter++;
    }

}
```

I know I can use fscanf somehow and I know it should be much simpler than this. I just need a *pointer (pun intended) in the right direction!

Comment: Every call to `fscanf` eats up another character. Read one at a time, then immediately inspect it.

Comment: What should I be looking for? Should it be something as seeing if fscanf(ifp2, "%c ", &file[i]) == ':' then don't do anything?

Comment: you know you can can all of this and just use an appropriate configured (pseudo) `while fgetc { if (isalpha) fputc } ` loop, right?

Comment: No how would I use that? I've never done it before.

Comment: [Something like this](http://pastebin.com/wHVCWamA).

Comment: `while ((c=fgetc(ifp) != EOF))
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            if(isalpha((unsigned char)c))
            {
                fputc(c, file[i]);
            }
        }

    }`

it doesnt put the letters into my array

Comment: Don't paste walls of code into comments please. And the link I provided should demonstrate *you don't need an array* if all you're doing is dumping alphabetic-only char data from your input file or stdin to stdout. The array would be part of the "all of this" that mentioned earlier could be canned if done with a trivial fgetc/fputc loop.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. And _I do need an array_ because I'm going to be doing something later to the letters in my program. I'm not just simply reading them and regurgitating them. I need to store these values in an array and then change them and reprint the array like that. But I ONLY need the letters which is for some reason becoming difficult for me to do :( is there a website you know of that easily explains fgetc and fputc?

Comment: honestly, it looks like you're far more confused about how *loop control* works than api functions. What possible use do you plan on getting out of invoking `fscanf` up-to-10000 times *inside* a loop that is already designed to enumerate every char in a file? Regardless, the mechanism for growing a alpha-char-only dynamic array would be [something like this](http://pastebin.com/U9imqgPh), but I doubt you're going to understand it without a more concrete understanding of loop control *first*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char c;
  fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
         printf("Couldn't open file  for reading.\n");
         exit(0);
      }
  while (fscanf(fp, "%c",&c) != EOF)
    {
      if (isalpha(c))
    printf("%c", c);
    }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I can work with this! Now I'll just work on putting the values into the array :)

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to take c and put it into my array File?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to print output in another file?

Answer (score 0):

Technially, you can use fscanf to ignore directly (the `*` suppresses assignment):

```
fscanf(in, "%*[^A-Za-z]%c", &c);
```

It's not incredibly useful in this case - intpreted format strings are slow. I would just use `fgetc`.

Comment: when i do

`while (fscanf(ifp2, "%c", &file[i]) != EOF)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
             fscanf(ifp2, "%*[^A-Za-z]%c", &file[i]);
        }
    }`
it just crashes :C

Comment: @Enigma ... why are you nesting loops like that?